# Can I use Valgrind to add my own defined assembly instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, valgrind

I want to define a pseudo instruction and want to simulate on valgrind or any other x86 simulator. Is there a way to do that? Suppose I want to add an instruction like MOVDB RX,RY in my instruction set,is there a way to do that using valgrind or any other tool?

Comment: Generally, if it's open source you can take the code and run with it (e.g. add anything you like). But why would you?

Comment: QEMU is (relatively) easy to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Well theoretically everything is possible. But why adding a new instruction? I am sure that this instruction can be simulated using other instruction, so writing a macro would solve the problem.

On the other hand, moderating the source code of any assembler is a really advanced project.

A nice example is that memory to memory transfers are not allowed in (most) x86 assemblers. 
That problem is easily solved using a (simple) macro.